# iOS Bluetooth BLE read data maximum size

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an iOS app that reads/writes on a BLE device. The device is sending me data over 20 bytes long and I see they get trimmed. Based on the following thread

[Bluetooth LE maximum transmission size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26214362/bluetooth-le-maximum-transmission-size)

it looks like iOS is trimming the data. That thread shows the solution on how to write bigger data sizes, but how do we `read` info larger than 20 bytes?

Comment: You need the device to send packets that are smaller than the MTU.

Comment: Just for some context, how is the device sending you data over 20 bytes? Is it packetizing them into 20 byte chunks? Has it changed the MTU? I will say that any peripheral sending > 20 bytes per packet to a phone is going to cause trouble all around until Android + iOS become compliant with BLE 4.2 and 5.0 - edit: forgot an MTU link https://punchthrough.com/blog/posts/maximizing-ble-throughput-part-2-use-larger-att-mtu

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking at this post years later like I am, we ran into this question as well at one point. I would like to share some helpful hints for data larger than 20 bytes.

- Since the data is larger than one packet can handle, you will need to send it in multiple packets. It helps significantly if your data ALWAYS ends with some sort of END byte. For us, our end byte gives the size of the total byte array so we can check that at the end of reading.
- Create a loop that checks for a packet constantly and stops when it receives that end byte (would also be good to have a timeout for that loop).
- Make sure to clear the "buffer" when you start a new read.
- It is nice to have an "isBusy" boolean to keep track of whether another function is currently waiting to read from the device. This prevents read overlaps. For us, if the port is currently busy, we wait a half second and try again.

Hope this helps!